# udp receive java can't run in php

Tags: java, php, networking

I'm new to UDP programming in java. I've a book that contains the code both the sender and receiver in java. When I make the jar and run from cmd the code run nicely.

The problem is start when i being asked to make a php to run the .jar the receiver can't receive anything.. the receiver only work when use the cmd. The sender is fine because it already can send both using cmd or php

receiver code :

```
package packetreceiver;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Packetreceiver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int z = 0;
while (z<5){
try
{
  DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(2000);
  DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[256], 256);
  socket.receive(packet);
  System.out.println("Binding to local port 2000");
  System.out.println("Bound to local port " + socket.getLocalPort());
  System.out.println("Packet received!");

  InetAddress remote_addr = packet.getAddress();
  System.out.println("Sent by : " + remote_addr.getHostAddress());
  System.out.println("Sent from: " + packet.getPort());


  ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(packet.getData());
  for (int i = 0; i < packet.getLength(); i++)
  {
    int data = bin.read();
    if (data == -1) {
      break;
    }
    System.out.print((char)data);
  }
  socket.close();
  System.out.println();
}
catch (IOException ioe)
{
  System.err.println("Error - " + ioe);
}
z++;
}
}
}
```

php :

```
<?php
exec("java -Xmx1g -jar packetreceiver.jar",$output);
foreach($output as $value) {
  echo $value;
  echo "</br>";
};
?>
```

Please help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on PHP side. Your ***exec*** fails but since you do not handle errors you do not know that. PHP has problem finding things here so you may try to play with paths. For example - here is how it might look like for some theoretical ***Test.class*** file:

```
exec("\"c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java.exe\" -cp c:/php Test", $output, $ret);

if ( $ret == 0 )
{
    echo "operation failed\n";
    exit(1);
}

foreach($output as $line)
{
   echo $line;
}
```

Comment: I didn't think the path is the problem because i put the jar in same place with receiver.php in htdocs, I usually use that with no problem and from where you get $ret? but i will try it